# Reverse of each value in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table with even number of rows. For eg- a table Employee with two columns Name and EmpCode. The table looks like

```
Name          EmpCode
Ajay          7
Vikash        5
Shalu         4
Hari          8
Anu           1
Puja          9
```

Now, I want my output in reverse of EmpCode like:

```
Name          EmpCode
Ajay          9
Vikash        1
Shalu         8
Hari          4
Anu           5
Puja          7
```

I need to run this query in SQL Server.

Comment: What determines to order that the Employees are currently in?

Comment: @RameshRajendran Empcode 7 is at the start of the first dataset, and at the end in the second. Conversely,  EmpCode 9 is at the end of the first, and start of the second. The order of the data is reversed. The problem, however, is I can see no way to achieve the order the OP has with their supply data. both `ORDER BY [Name]` and `ORDER BY EmpCode` would not supply the initial ordering.

Comment: A table has not natural order.  A select without an order by can be in any order.

Comment: do you have any id or primary key (int) column in your table.

Comment: With nothing in the data to define the order this is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP hasn't replied, I'll post a little explanation for them instead. As everyone has eluded to, tables in SQL Server have no built in ordering. Your data is stored in what is known as a HEAP. This means, when you run a query without an `ORDER BY` your data can return in **any** order that the Server feels like. With small datasets this *might* be in the order you inserted it in, but that's just it (it might).

When you get to larger datasets, and when you have multiple cores running on the operation, then the order of a `SELECT * FROM [Table];` is more likely to not be the order in insertion, and is more likely to be random which each instance of running the query. I have several tables where a `SELECT TOP 1 *...` will return a different row **every** time I run the query; even with the `CLUSTERED INDEX`.

The only, yes **only**, way to guarantee the order is by using `ORDER BY`. Now, you *might* have another column which you haven't shared that you can order by, but if not, perhaps this (very) simple example will at least assist you, if nothing else:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee ([Name] varchar(10), EmpCode tinyint);

INSERT INTO #Employee
VALUES ('Ajay',7),
       ('Vikash',5),
       ('Shalu',4),
       ('Hari',8),
       ('Anu',1),
       ('Puja',9);
GO
--Just SELECT *. ORDER is NOT guaranteed, but, due to the low volume of data, will probably be in the order by insertion
SELECT *
FROM #Employee;

--But, we want to reverse the order, so, let's add an ORDER BY
SELECT *
FROM #Employee
ORDER BY [Name];

--Oh! That didn't work (duh). Let's try again
SELECT *
FROM #Employee
ORDER BY Empcode;

--Nope, this isn't working. That's because your data has nothing related to it's insertion order. So, let's give it one:
GO
DROP TABLE #Employee;

CREATE TABLE #Employee (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), --Oooo, what is this?
                        [Name] varchar(10),
                        EmpCode tinyint);

INSERT INTO #Employee
VALUES ('Ajay',7),
       ('Vikash',5),
       ('Shalu',4),
       ('Hari',8),
       ('Anu',1),
       ('Puja',9);
GO
--Now look
SELECT *
FROM #Employee;

--So, we can use an ORDER BY, and get the correct order too
SELECT [Name],
       Empcode
FROM #Employee
ORDER BY ID;

--So, we got the right ORDER using an ORDER BY. Now we can do something about the ordering:
--We'll need a CTE for this:
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RN1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN2
    FROM #Employee)
SELECT R1.[Name],
       R2.EmpCode
FROM RNs R1
     JOIN RNs R2 ON R1.RN1 = R2.RN2;

GO
DROP TABLE #Employee;
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, your code sample indicates you misunderstood the question. The OP does not ask how to return the rows in the opposite order, but rather how to return the `empcode` in the opposite order, while keeping the `name` in the same order as in the first query.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that part, thanks @ZoharPeled . I'll make an amendment.

Comment: Now you're talking :-) +1.